# MVC PHP разделы, рубрики

Tags: php_pdo, mvc, ооп, php

Всем привет!</br>
Делаю сайт с каталогом товаров. Решил сделать с помощью mvc-паттерна.</br>

url разбирается на: site.ru/контроллер/метод/аргумент/значение/...

Когда захожу в каталог, адрес имеет вид:</br>
*site.ru/catalog* - показываются главные разделы,</br>

если заходим в раздел, </br>
*site.ru/catalog/razdel-1* - надо показать подкатегории взятые из базы

Как мне правильно обрабатывать динамический запрос, если в данный момент, система ищет несуществующий метод *razdel-1* ?

Вот так я разбираю URL (libs/**bootstrap.php**):

```
function __construct() {
        $url = isset($_GET ['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim ( $url, '/' );
        $url = explode ( '/', $url );           
        if(empty($url[0])) {
            require 'controllers/index.php';
            $controller = new Index();
            $controller->index();
            return false;
        }

        $file = 'controllers/' . $url [0] . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) { require $file; }
        else { $this->error(); }

        $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if (isset ( $url [2] )) {
            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url [1]} ( $url [2] );
            } else { $this->error(); }
        } else {
            if (isset ( $url [1] )) {
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
                    $controller->{$url [1]} ();
                } else { $this->error(); }
            } else {$controller->index(); }
        }
    }
```

libs/**Controller.php**

```
class Controller {
    function __construct() { $this->view = new View(); }

    public function loadModel($name) {
        $path = 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require 'models/'.$name.'_model.php';
            $modelName = $name . '_Model';
            $this->model = new $modelName();
        }
    }
}
```

libs/**Model.php**

```
class Model {
    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }
}
```

libs/**View.php**

```
class View {
    function __construct() {
    }
    public function render($name, $noInclude = false) {
        if ($noInclude == true) {
            require 'views/'. $name. '.php';
        } else {
            require 'views/header.php';
            require 'views/'. $name. '.php';
            require 'views/footer.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Вот контроллер каталога, controllers/**catalog.php**

```
class Catalog extends Controller {
    function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }

    public function index() {
        $this->view->displayMenuCategories = $this->model->displayMenuCategories();
        $this->view->render('catalog/index');
    }
}
```

А вот модель каталога, models/**catalog_model.php**,

```
class Catalog_Model extends Model {

    public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); }

    /* = Берем из базы главные категории =... */
    public function getCategoriesList() {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT*FROM `categories` WHERE `parent_cat` = 0");
        $sth->execute();
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0) { return $sth->fetchAll();}
                else { return "таких нет"; }
    }

    /* ...= Выводим на экран главные категории = */
    public function displayMenuCategories() {
        foreach (self::getCategoriesList() as $key => $value) {$vod =  "<a href='catalog/".$value['linkName']."'>".$value['name_cat']."</a>";}

        return $vod;
    }
}
```

Направьте плз в нужное русло. Не получается нагуглить ((

заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

вы немного намудрили, сделайте разбор URL в результате которого всегда будет получаться набор контроллер и метод, к этому добавте проверку на кастомные руты, что-то типа если контроллер == 'catalog' и аргрументов нет, то метод будет 'method_name' и дефолтные аргументы этого метода будут такие array('arg1' => 'val1'), если в этом случае метод определился (а в вашем втором случае он определится как 'razdel-1'), то метод всеравно останется дефолтным методом, а определившийся метод станет параметром. Все это будет true только в том случае когда имя контроллера определится как 'catalog' во всех остальных случаях значения контроллера метода и праметров будет определяться по изначальному плану 'контроллер/метод/аргумент/значение/'. Конфигурацию кастомных рутов лучше вынести отдельно и подгружать в алгоритм разбора URL.

PS определение коннекта к базе данных лучше перенести в parent класс, сделать его абстрактным и общим для последующих моделей

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!